# Масштабирование сайта

Tags: html, css

Привет...Старая проблема.

При увеличении сntr + блоки увеличиваються в размере.Размер шрифта в нем также увеличивается.Что может мне помочь чтобы при увеличении масштаба блока шрифт шел пропорциально изменению параметров блока,чтобы текст не выходил за пределы блока?

Смотрел в сторону задания размера шрифта в % и em.
Насколько хорошо задать параметры блоку min-width,max-width .Он вроде частично решает проблему.Блок увеличивается только до предельного размера.
Размер шрифта в % вычисляется от размера блока или шрифта родителя?
width В % будет вычислятся от ширины родителя или от размера шрифта родителя?

Мне поставлена задача только разобратся со шрифтом.Можно найти решение?
**Внимание : не требуется поддержка IE.**

Answer (score 1):

Тебе здесь надо узать `Media Queries`

Comment: Точно?При масштабировании сайта чтобы разобратся с шрифтами нужно media-queries?

Comment: Сорри не правильно прочитал, когда ты маштабируешь окно, ты не сможешь контролить  его, надо изначально писать правильно! насколько я понимаю ты верстаешь responsive

Comment: Что значит масштабирование сайта? Если Вы делаете верстку под различные разрешения экрана, то как сказали выше, нужно использовать media queries. При этом мастабированием разумные люди верстку не проверяют. По крайней мере в Firefox и Chrome для этого есть встроенные средства, которые как бы меняют разрешение экрана и без масштабирования.